# Acestream recording streams (Arch Linux)

Tags: streaming, recording

I have had a good around the internet before coming here and asking for some help.

So, I would like to record an Acestream stream.

I have tried various command-line variations but have had no luck:

```
acestream-launcher acestreamID -p "mpv --record-file=/home/dave/Desktop/acestreamtestrecord1.mp4"
acestream-launcher -p "mpv --stream-/home/dave/Desktop/acestreamtestrecord2.mp4" acestreamID
```